# Responsive Code Only Showing Desktop and Not Mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

Wondering if anyone can help. I am trying to build just a basic responsive HTML page for our students feedback, but my code just doesn't seem to be working. It will only show the desktop version.

**CSS STYLE**

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
  .hide-for-small-only {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 0em), screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .show-for-small-only {
    display: none !important; } }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/haveyoursay-headerv2.png" alt="Have Your Say" title="Have Your Say" /></div>

<!-- MOBILE -->
<div class="show-for-small-only">
    <div id="whatsonyourmind-mob" style="margin: 10px; float: left; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="https://sthelens.ac.uk/whatsonyourmind" target="_blank" style="border: 0px;"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/whatsonyourmind-img.png" alt="What's On Your Mind" title="What's On Your Mind" /></a>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #EC008C;">INSTANT ACTION &amp; RESPONSE<br /><br /></p>
    <hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"><a href="http://vle.sthelens.ac.uk/mod/questionnaire/view.php?id=25059" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color: #000;">What's On Your Mind is a direct channel to the senior managers of St Helens College. Just hit the button and you can easily submit your ideas or feedback online. You will always receive a response to let you know what we are doing.</a></p></div>
    
    <div id="studentsurvey-mob" style="margin: 10px; float: left;width: 100%; max-width: 100%; clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="/studentsurveys" target="_blank" style="border: 0px;"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/studentsurvey-img.png" alt="Student Survey" title="Student Survey"/></a>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #199CD8;">PROVIDE STRUCTURED FEEDBACK FOR LONG TERM CHANGE</p><hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"><a href="/studentsurveys" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color: #000;">We run a student survey each term to help us understand your experiences on your course and at College. We analyse the results from these surveys and then use this to make change and improvement for future years.</a></p></div>
    
    <div id="studentreps-mob" style="margin: 10px; float: left; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="http://vle.sthelens.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=1534" style="border: 0px;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/studentreps-img.png" alt="Student Reps" title="Student Reps" /></a>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #EC008C;">RAISE POINTS FOR GROUP DISCUSSION WITH OTHERS<br /><br /></p>
    <hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"><a href="http://vle.sthelens.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=1534" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000;" target="_blank">Each programme has a nominated Student Rep who attends a Department Student Reps' meeting. If there is something you wish to raise, let them know and they can take to the next meeting. The issue may then be raised at the next Student Council meeting by the department's Curriculum Area Rep. These points are then fed back to senior managers and governors of the College.</a></p></div>
    
    <div id="personaltutor-mob" style="margin: 10px; float: left;width: 100%; max-width: 100%; clear: both; text-align: center;"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/personaltutor-img.png" alt="Personal Tutor" title="Personal Tutor" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #199CD8;">PERSONALISED FACE TO FACE SUPPORT <br /></p>
    <hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
     <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Your personal tutor is always on hand to help you with any immediate issues or problems that you might be having. Have a chat to them.</p></div> 
    
</div>

    
<!-- DESKTOP -->
<div class="hide-for-small-only">
    <div id="whatsonyourmind" style="margin: 10px; float: left; width: 22%; text-align: center;"><a href="https://sthelens.ac.uk/whatsonyourmind" target="_blank" style="border: 0px;"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/whatsonyourmind-img.png" alt="What's On Your Mind" title="What's On Your Mind" /></a>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #EC008C;">INSTANT ACTION &amp; RESPONSE<br /><br /></p>
    <hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"><a href="http://vle.sthelens.ac.uk/mod/questionnaire/view.php?id=25059" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color: #000;">What's On Your Mind is a direct channel to the senior managers of St Helens College. Just hit the button and you can easily submit your ideas or feedback online. You will always receive a response to let you know what we are doing.</a></p></div>
        
    <div id="studentsurvey" style="margin: 10px; float: left; width: 22%; text-align: center;"><a href="/studentsurveys" target="_blank" style="border: 0px;"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/studentsurvey-img.png" alt="Student Survey" title="Student Survey"/></a>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #199CD8;">PROVIDE STRUCTURED FEEDBACK FOR LONG TERM CHANGE</p><hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"><a href="/studentsurveys" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color: #000;">We run a student survey each term to help us understand your experiences on your course and at College. We analyse the results from these surveys and then use this to make change and improvement for future years.</a></p></div>
    
    <div id="studentreps" style="margin: 10px; float: left; width: 22%; text-align: center;"><a href="http://vle.sthelens.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=1534" style="border: 0px;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/studentreps-img.png" alt="Student Reps" title="Student Reps" /></a>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #EC008C;">RAISE POINTS FOR GROUP DISCUSSION WITH OTHERS<br /><br /></p>
    <hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"><a href="http://vle.sthelens.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=1534" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000;" target="_blank">Each programme has a nominated Student Rep who attends a Department Student Reps' meeting. If there is something you wish to raise, let them know and they can take to the next meeting. The issue may then be raised at the next Student Council meeting by the department's Curriculum Area Rep. These points are then fed back to senior managers and governors of the College.</a></p></div>
    
    <div id="personaltutor" style="margin: 10px; float: left; width: 22%; text-align: center;"><img src="http://www.sthelens.ac.uk/haveyoursay/images/personaltutor-img.png" alt="Personal Tutor" title="Personal Tutor" />
    <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; color: #199CD8;">PERSONALISED FACE TO FACE SUPPORT <br /></p>
    <hr style="border: solid 2px #000; width: 40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
     <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Your personal tutor is always on hand to help you with any immediate issues or problems that you might be having. Have a chat to them.</p></div>    
</div>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks, Sam

Comment: Have you swapped your mins and maxs?  `@media screen and (max-width: 0em)` would mean a screen that was no wider than `0`, right?

Comment: this code works fine on edge. Remove `(max-width: 0em)` as suggested by Alexander.

Comment: Actually, I just verified @SagarV - the code as you have it appears to be doing what is expected; if I shrink and grow the viewport it hides/shows the different sections.  How is this failing to work for your purposes?

Comment: Also if you define an upper limit `39.9375em` and lower limit `40em`, you won't see anything on devices with width between `39.9375em` and `40em`. Set the break points `39.99` and `40`

Comment: Do you have a meta tag to stop the browser scaling? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Comment: Hi Guys. I would just like to say a huge thank you. I made all the amendments you suggested above and it is working perfectly now. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nearly always better to approach responsive CSS starting from mobile and working upwards. Use min-width rather than max-width because it's easier to start from zero and work upwards and it avoids awkward boundaries such as 39.9375em.

The simplest solution is

```
.hide-for-small-only {display:none;}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    .hide-for-small-only {display:block;}
    .show-for-small-only {display:none;}
}
```

Imagine a browser window whose width starts at zero and then grows indefinitely. This solution starts off hiding the "hide-for-small-only" element and showing the "show-for-small-only" element. Then when the browser width hits 40em, it shows the "hide-for-small-only" element and hides the "show-for-small-only" element.

Comment: Thank you so much Kate. I have now got the code working. Appreciate your help.